# Add a CMS block to Minicart Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I was looking to add a CMS block to Magento 2. I understand that I would need to edit the minicart.phtml in my theme file to make reference to the CMS block but I can't for the life of me figure out what layout XML file I need to edit and what I need to add there.

Answer (score 1):

So I actually just figured this out and thought I would share how I did it.

I copied the following file into my theme folder as below.

**FROM:** `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

**TO:**

```
app/design/frontend/themeprovider/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml
```

I created a CMS block named minicart message with identifier minicart_message in the magento admin panel.

I added my code to the default.xml file directly below  the following line

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
```

Here is the code I added

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="minicart_message">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="minicart_message" xsi:type="string">minicart_message</argument>
                </arguments>
</block>
```

I then edited my `mini_cart.phtml` in my theme `app/design/frontend/themeprovider/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/`

This is the code I added to where I wanted the custom CMS block to display.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('minicart_message')->toHtml();?>
```

Hope that helps anyone else trying to figure this out.